# Wrong wolfram alpha result for $\sin(\frac{3 \pi}{2})$

Tags: trigonometry, infinite-product, wolfram-alpha

I'm trying to compute $\sin(\frac{3 \pi}{2})$ using sin infinite product on wolfram alpha yet it gives me the answer 1 . Shouldnt the answer be -1? [here is the result wolfram alpha gives me image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0Oac.jpg)

Here is the infinite product formula for $\sin(x)$. [Sin(x) infinite
product image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eKj2.jpg)

Comment: Yes, it definitely should be -1, and I got that answer when I tried just now—I don't know what's happened on your end.

Comment: I don't know, but [removing the factor of $3\pi/2$ from the front](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Product%5B%281-%283%2F2%29%5E2%2Fn%5E2%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2Cinfty%7D%5D) gives both a positive and a negative value as its output, so something weird is going on.

Comment: @SpadorYedi is there a way for u to send an image of the result u got from wolfram alpha

Comment: [Here you go.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atBz9.png) I did this on pc so maybe there's something different on mobile?

Comment: But the answer should be -1 but you got 1. I did mine on mobile

Comment: WolframAlpha is wrong. I don't know how they're getting "approximately equal to $1$" when it should be $-1$. But when you make the upper bound as large as $10000$, it approximates the product to be very close to $-1$, which could mean WolframAlpha is thrown off by the $\infty$ sign.

Comment: What is that $\zeta^{(1,0)}$ in the Wolfram output?  What is the infinite-product fact about it that is mangled in this output?

Answer (score 2):

The product
$$
\frac{3\pi}{2}\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{(3\pi/2)^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)
$$
has one negative factor
$$
\left(1-\frac{(3\pi/2)^2}{1^2\pi^2}\right)
$$
and all other factors positive.  So that infinite product certainly does not converge to $1$.